# How to align input fields underneath each other?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgWdMW

I'm trying to align the inputfields so that they start all at the same point, I've tried multiple things since yesterday, positioning is harder than I thought..

## A Survey Form

```
<p id="description"> Let us know how we can improve FFC</p>

<div class="labels">

  <div>
  <label for="name">* Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"          required>
         </div>


    <div class="one">     
  <label for="email">* Email: </label>
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="enter your mail">
    </div>

    <div>
  <label for="age">* Age: </label>
  <input type="number" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Age">
    </div>

    <div>
  <label for="Number">* Number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Number" placeholder="Enter your Number">
    </div>
     </div>´
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define a width for your labels, this means they all take up the same amount of space next to the input boxes. For this you need the following css:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

There's also a slight issue with the "Age" box being slighly larger than the others due to the number input and padding (for me on firefox at least). You could set a width on the input boxes to fix this e.g.

```
input {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqKJBg)

Comment: Wow... I feel kinda dumb now, im new to this but you just solved my problem. So does "display: inline-block" basically "put the labelwords(name,age etc)" in a box and set a maximum width thats why it makes its centered because of this? Also how do you figure out how many pixels it is, should I just test if i get cases like that? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @KAENE yeah, labels are inline elements by default so don't take any notice of width, so setting inline-block allows us to set the width, but still allows them on the same line as other elements. Yes, I'd just do it by trial and error until it looks right.